# Приватные свойства класса в ООП

Tags: javascript, php, c#, ооп

Сейчас пишу на js, столкнулся с ООП. Я не понимаю зачем нужны приватные свойства (в js это #, в других `private`), да можно обращаться только в классе, но из вне нельзя. Но есть `set` и `get`, с помощью которых можно получать данные и изменять их. Тогда в чем смысл этих свойств?

Comment: А зачем делать сет и гет на приватные свойства?

Comment: Смысл в том, чтобы не лезть своими руками из других классов в другой класс, а работать с классом как с отдельным органом программы (если так можно выразиться). Смысл private, public,  protected...итд итп в том, чтобы легче писалось код непосредственно программисту

Comment: @Aarnihauta Как сделать так, чтобы программисту легче писалось код?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Я не понимаю зачем нужны приватные свойства

Для сокрытия деталей реализации. По хорошему вам стоит взять за практику делать все поля приватными по умолчанию и открывать доступ только лишь к тем полям, к которым действительно должен быть доступ извне.

**Пример**: есть некий класс, у которого для своих внутренних целей есть внутри счетчик, обновляющий свое значение каждую секунду. Это значение должно где-то храниться. И хранить его в публичном свойстве - плохая идея, потому что значение этого счетчика можно будет изменить извне, что потенциально повлечет сбои в работе программы. Хорошая идея - хранить это значение в приватном свойстве.

> Но есть set и get, с помощью которых можно получать данные и изменять их

А это уже реализация публичного интерфейса, обертки, с которой будет работать пользователь. Почему именно через `get` и `set`? Например, чтобы валидировать передаваемые приватному полю значения. Если просто сделать публичное свойство, то в него извне можно будет записать что угодно, что может привести к неправильному поведению (в лучшем случае). Если же позволить изменять занчение приватного свойства через `get`-`set` публичный интерфейс, то перед записью нового значения можно проверять его валидность, и в случае, если значение невалидно, выбрасывать исключение (как вариант).

**Пример**: (с тем же счетчиком). Представим, что у пользователя все-таки должна быть возможность изменить значение счетчика (которое хранится где-то в приватном свойстве). Напрмер, обнулить его. В таком случае внутрь сеттера как раз-таки и можно добавить соответствующую проверку. Если передан ноль - устанавливаем его в качестве нового значения. Если передано что-то иное - игнорируем или выбрасываем исключение или выводим сообщение об ошибке - что угодно. Пример немного притянут за уши на самом деле, поскольку более логичным все же будет завести отдельный публичный метод, вызвав который значение счетчика обнулится. Но для иллюстрации, думаю, пойдет.

Помимо того, что сказано выше, `getter`'ы и `setter`'ы также принятно использовать для обновления связанных значений. Например, если у класса есть поля `firstName` и `lastName` и скрытое поле `fullName`, то при изменении `firstName` прямо в сеттере хорошей идеей будет и обновить значение `fullName` соответственно.

Иной пример - сохранение данных. Представьте, что вам нужно сохранять значение свойства где-то снаружи, чтобы оно не терялось при завершении работы программы. Это может быть что угодно - localStorage, запись в файл, отправка на сервер. Сеттер в этом случае - отличное место, чтобы инициировать запрос о сохранении данных при их изменении.

Ну а касательно геттеров, они, по сути, просто являются общепринятым способом для предоставления возможности считывать скрытые данные. Также часто используются для форматирования вывода.

Еще **важно** понимать, что никто вас не обязывает заводить пару геттер-сеттер для каждого приватного свойства. Делайте это только там, где действительно необходимо.

Comment: "Еще важно понимать, что никто вас не обязывает заводить пару геттер-сеттер для каждого приватного свойства. Делайте это только там, где действительно необходимо."  --- имхо, это, как раз, должно быть самым первым пунктом в ответе :))